# Loading images from server to AnnotationView in Apple Map in iOS10 using Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10

Here is my code :

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        // Don't want to show a custom image if the annotation is the user's location.
        guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {
            return nil
        }

        // Better to make this class property
        let annotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier"

        var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?
        if let dequeuedAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier) {
            annotationView = dequeuedAnnotationView
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        }
        else {
            annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
            let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "abc.png") , for: .normal)
            annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
        }

        if let annotationView = annotationView {
            // Configure your annotation view here

            annotationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            annotationView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
            let url = URL(string: "abc url ")
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
            let myPicture = UIImage(data: data!)
            let thumb1 = myPicture?.resizeWith(percentage: 0.1)
            annotationView.image = thumb1

        }

        return annotationView
    }
```

But it is taking more time to load images, also images clusterred at one point initially?

Kindly suggest me how to load images from URL into `AnnotationView` custom image without creating custom class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does the url come from? Your code seems to have three optimization opportunities. 1. Obtaining the url and picture at that url beforehand. 2. Getting the UIImage before the delegate is called. 3. Resizing the image in the delegate call takes time.

Comment: okey , well if i have an array of image url and i need to show different image then how to do it in viewforannotation method @MacUserT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have the exact same problem, but I needed to load an array of images from the photos library as a call out image. The way I solved this problem is to have the class start with two arrays

```
class MyMapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    var urlArray = [url]()
    var thumbnailArray = [UIImage]()
    //and whatever vars and lets you need

    override viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        thumbnailArray = getArrayOfThumbnails(from listOFURLs: urlArray)

        //Now here set up your map view and create the annotations 
    }
```

The function getArrayOfThumbnails(from listOfURLs:) can be created in a separate class or in the view controller depending on your app and what the model is containing the urls or images.

```
func getArrayOfThumbnails(from listOfURLs: [url]) -> [UIImage] {

    let imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10)
    var returnThumbnails = [UIImage]()
    var counter = 0

    for url in listOfURLs {
        let myImage = CIImage(contentOf: url)

        returnTumbnails[counter] = UIImage(ciImage: myImage.cropping(to: imageRect)
    }
    return returnThumbnails
}
```

Then in the map view delegate method you can get the thumbnail out of the prepared array of thumbnails. Since I don't know what the criteria are of which image to pick, I put the thumbnails in an array. However, you can also put them in a dictionary and get them out of the dictionary based on the criteria you have for picking the right image with the specific annotation.

In my app fetching the images out of the photos library goes super fast and doesn't clog the UI. If you have a lot of images to load from a server with low bandwidth I would call the getArrayOfThumbnails(from listOfURLs:) from a different queue than the main queue to prevent clogging the UI. You might need to see how this works out with the timing. If the map view delegate calls the array of thumbnails before the function getArrayOfThumbnails(from listOfURLs:) returns the result, you might end up without images. You should then see if you can get the images in batches.

Hope this helps.